# How to target <img> inside iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a webpage which is the main `index.html` and another `projects_imgs.html` which will be the iframe src inside the `index.html`

Inside the `projects_imgs.html` there will be images. What I want to do is,

In `index.html` I want to add `<a>` tags that links to the images inside `projects_imgs.html`, so whenever the user clicks these links the iframe loads the clicked link that targets a specific image

get the idea?

So far here is the code of index.html:

```html
    <!-- Projects section -->
    <div class="section projects-section" id="section4">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-9">
          <iframe class="pull-right" width="85%" height="700px" src="projects_imgs.html" name="projects_gallery"></iframe>
        </div>
        </div>
        <p><a href="projects_imgs.html" target="projects_gallery">Images</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and projects_imgs.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MH-Shukri Projects Gallery</title>
<!--- Bootstrap CSS --->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
<!--- Bootstrap Theme --->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>
<style>
body {
  background-color: #34312C;
}

img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/projects/Faf/1.jpg"/>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/projects/Faf/2.jpg"/>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/projects/Faf/3.jpg"/>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/projects/Faf/4.jpg"/>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/projects/Faf/5.jpg"/>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/projects/Faf/6.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So no other way? other than PHP

Answer (score 0):

To implement such a logic in html only is not possible i think.
I suggest you to use PHP to implement this logic. Here is a small example:

index.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        Images: <br>
        <a href="images.html?image=1"> Image 1 </a> <br>
        <a href="images.html?image=2"> Image 2 </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

These links call images.html with the parameter "image". As you can see, we set "image" to 1 or 2, depends on what the user is clicking on.

images.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        if($_GET["image"] == 1)
        {
            echo "<img src='Image1'/>";
        }
        if($_GET["image"] == 2)
        {
            echo "<img src='Image2'/>";
        }           
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

In images.html you decide with an IF Statement. If it was 1, then you just call the  with the Image 1. If 2....

You can use that to implement it with your iFrame. But keep in mind that you need a webserver who understands PHP to get this running!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out!

I do it like this:

```js
function setURL(url){
    document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="index.html" width="50%" height="250px"></iframe> <br>
<a href="#" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/1.jpg')">A01-FAF-1</a><br>
<a href="#" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/2.jpg')">A01-FAF-2</a><br>
<a href="#" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/3.jpg')">A01-FAF-3</a><br>
<a href="#" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/4.jpg')">A01-FAF-4</a><br>
<a href="#" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/5.jpg')">A01-FAF-5</a><br>
<a href="#" type="button" onclick="setURL('imgs/projects/ARCH/A01-FAF/6.jpg')">A01-FAF-6</a><br>
```

Just replace the images with some random google images link to test it.